# Multiple If Statements in Bash Script

Tags: bash, if-statement, scripting, raspberry-pi

I am trying to make a bash script with the output based on the input.
My code looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash  
echo "Letter:"
read a
if a=3
then 
        echo "LOL"
fi
if a=4
then
        echo "ROFL"
fi
```

But when I enter 3 or 4, I get both `LOL` and `ROFL`.
Is there a way for me to get `LOL` for 3 and `ROFL` for 4?
Sorry if I'm using incorrect terms and stuff, I'm new to bash scripting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `bash`, `a=3` is an assignment, not a test.  Use, e.g.:

```
if [ "$a" = 3 ]
```

Inside `[...]`, the equal sign tests for string (character) equality.  If you want to test for numeric value instead, then use '-eq` as in:

```
if [ "$a" -eq 3 ]
```

The quotes around "$a" above are necessary to avoid an "operator" error when `a` is empty.

`bash` also offers a conditional expressions that begin with `[[` and have a different format.  Many like the `[[` format better (it avoids, for example, the quote issue mentioned above) but the cost is loss of compatibility with other shells.  In particular, note that `dash`, which is the default shell (`/bin/sh`) for scripts under Debian-derived distributions, does not have `[[`.

Answer (score 2):

Bash thinks you're trying to *assign* a variable by saying `a=3`. You can do the following to fix this:

- Use the `=` operator whilst referencing the variable with a `$`, like so: `if [[ $a = 3 ]]`
- Use the `-eq` operator, which is special and doesn't require you to reference the variable with a `$`, but **may *not* be compatible** with all `sh`-derived shells: `if [[ a -eq 3 ]]`. If you wish to use `-eq` without Bash reference the variable: `if [[ $a -eq 3 ]]`

**Note**:

The double square brackets `[[ ... ]]` are a preferred format with specifically Bash conditionals. `[ ... ]` is good with any `sh`-derived shell (`zsh`, `tcsh`, etc).

Comment: @MistressDavid it is possible but not 100% compatible with other shells. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20794694/why-is-this-bash-conditional-valid).

Answer (score 2):

`if a=3` will assign value `3` to variable `a`
unless `a` is readonly variable, `if a=3` always returns TRUE
same for `if a=4`

To compare variable `a` with a value, you can do this `if [ $a = 3 ]`
so the script should change to

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Letter:"
read a
if [ $a = 3 ]
then
        echo "LOL"
fi
if [ $a = 4 ]
then
        echo "ROFL"
fi
```

Since `a` is read from user input, there is possibility user key in:

1. non numeric value
2. a string with empty space
3. nothing, user may just press Enter key

so a safer way to check is:

```
if [ "x$a" = "x3" ]
```

Comment: or you can just use ``[[ $a = 3 ]]``, no problems here.