# Why can you use -eq in Bash conditionals without adding a '$' before a variable name?

Tags: bash, variables, if-statement, conditional-statements

I was running some Bash conditional scripts and discovered if I run this:

```
#!/bin/bash

read foo

if [[ foo -eq 1 ]]; then
  echo "A"
fi

if [[ foo -eq 2 ]]; then
  echo "B"
fi
```

The conditionals work fine under Bash 4.2.25 without the use of `$foo`. Why does this work without referencing the variable with a `$`?

Comment: Basically because it is a `bash` [built-in command](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Conditional-Constructs) (compared with either the Bourne shell or the POSIX shell) and it has been decreed that variables do not need to be prefixed with `$` in this one context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the description of bash [Conditional Constructs](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Conditional-Constructs), it says that `[[ expression ]]` performs *arithmetic expansion* of the expression. If you then find the section on [Shell Arithmetic](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Arithmetic) it says:

> Within an expression, shell variables may also be referenced by name without using the parameter expansion syntax.

"parameter expansion syntax" refers to putting a `$` before the name.